# Adb devices listed but can't fastboot devices

Tags: android, adb

[ADB Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSrEo.png)

I can see my devices connected in adb devices but when i `adb reboot bootloader` My Devices can't been seen and can't use `fastboot devices`
i'v been trying restart my phone, turn off usb debugging and turn it on again, and reinstall universal adb driver

Please i need help

Comment: Try using a different cable, or a different USB Slot. Might help.

Comment: When device is in bootloader mode check device manager, some times the wrong river is loaded and you have to manually assign the USB device entry to the fastboot driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  **You need to install a fastboot driver for your device.**

In my case, I needed to go to [this URL](https://developer.sony.com/develop/drivers) and download the one for Sony Xperia XZ1 Compact -- but you will almost certainly have a different phone.  If your phone is not a Sony like mine, you'll have to find some other way to get the drivers you need.